# How to combine these two functions so one waits until it's finished and then runs the other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, sequelize.js, components

The two functions in question:

```
   const handleSubmit = async (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(songLink)
    const newSong = {
        songName,
        songLink,
        userId
    };
    const song = await dispatch(postSong(newSong))
        .catch(async (res) => {
            const data = await res.json()
            if (data && data.errors) setErrors(data.errors)
        })
    reset();
};

const uploadSong = (files) => {
    console.log(files[0])
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', songSelected)
    formData.append('upload_preset', 'd3gthd7l')
    Axios.post("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dyhfkvy6u/video/upload", formData).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.url, 'responseeee')
        setSongLink(response.data.url)
    })
}
```

I need the uploadSong function to finish the upload so I can get the response.data.url and save it to a variable, THEN handle the submit and add the variable to my database when creating the song. I'm not sure if it's something small or if I'm completely missing a concept. Should I return the url and then await the function?

The entire file:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

import { postSong } from "../../store/song";

import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

// import { Image, Audio } from 'cloudinary-react'


import Axios from 'axios'

const SongForm = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const [songName, setSongName] = useState("");
    const [songLink, setSongLink] = useState("");
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);

    const [songSelected, setSongSelected] = useState("")
    const [url, setUrl] = useState('')

    const reset = () => {
        setSongName("");
        setSongLink("");
        // setAlbumName('');
        // setArtistName('')
    };
    const user = useSelector((state) => state.session.user);
    const userId = user?.id

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {

        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(songLink)
        const newSong = {
            songName,
            songLink,
            userId
        };
        const song = await dispatch(postSong(newSong))
            .catch(async (res) => {
                const data = await res.json()
                if (data && data.errors) setErrors(data.errors)
            })
        reset();
    };

    const uploadSong = (files) => {
        console.log(files[0])
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('file', songSelected)
        formData.append('upload_preset', 'd3gthd7l')
        Axios.post("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dyhfkvy6u/video/upload", formData).then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data.url, 'responseeee')
            setSongLink(response.data.url)
        })
    }


    return (
        <div className="inputBox">
            <h1>Add A Song</h1>
            <ul>
                {errors.map((error, idx) => <li className='errors' key={idx}>{error}</li>)}
            </ul>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    onChange={(e) => setSongName(e.target.value)}
                    value={songName}
                    placeholder="Song Name"
                    name="Song Name"
                />
                {/* <input type="text"
                    type="text"
                    onChange={(e) => setSongLink(e.target.value)}
                    value={songLink}
                /> */}
                <input
                    // type="text"
                    // onChange={(e) => setSongLink(e.target.value)}
                    type='file'
                    onChange={(e) => { setSongSelected(e.target.files[0]) }}
                    // value={songLink}
                    placeholder="Song Link"
                    name="Audio File"
                />
                <button onClick={uploadSong} type="submit">Submit</button>

                {/* <Audio cloudName='dyhfkvy6u' publicId='https://res.cloudinary.com/dyhfkvy6u/image/upload/v1639007386/x8cgeebtzdfeou4p6bhw.png' /> */}

            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default SongForm;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a onSubmit handler for your form, but you are also assigning an onClick action for the form's submit button (with a button of type **submit**).

Namely:

`<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>`

`<button onClick={uploadSong} type="submit">Submit</button>`

The impact of this is two actions will fire.

If I were you, I would remove the onClick (on the button) or the onSubmit (on the form) so that you only have one action that happens.

Then, let's say you decide to keep your onSubmit as the action you want to fire, in that function I would call the two functions you want to perform. If the first function (upload) is async, I'd await its result before calling the next function.

Comment: Yes I committed to the handleSubmit function and had to put the dispatch after getting the response of the post. Thanks for the help!